# Notice: Undefined index: extension in vendor/magento/framework/File/Uploader.php on line 59

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-2.2.5

I am trying to import product image programmatically but I am getting Below  error

Notice: Undefined index: extension in vendor/magento/framework/File/Uploader.php on line 59

Code For Import Image:

```
    <?php

namespace Vendor\Demo\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

/*
 * Class ProductImagesImporter
 */

class ProductImagesImporter {

    /**
     * @var DirectoryList
     */
    protected $directoryList;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryEntryInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $attributeMediaGalleryEntryFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\Data\ImageContentInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $imageContentFactory;

    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\File\Mime
     */
    protected $mime;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File
     */
    protected $io;
    protected $product;
    /**
     * ProductImagesImporter constructor.
     * @param DirectoryList $directoryList
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File $io
     * @param \Magento\Framework\File\Mime $mime
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryEntryInterfaceFactory $attributeMediaGalleryEntryFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\Data\ImageContentInterfaceFactory $imageContentFactory
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
    DirectoryList $directoryList, \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File $io, \Magento\Framework\File\Mime $mime, \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryEntryInterfaceFactory $attributeMediaGalleryEntryFactory, \Magento\Framework\Api\Data\ImageContentInterfaceFactory $imageContentFactory, ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product
    ) {
        $this->directoryList = $directoryList;
        $this->mime = $mime;
        $this->io = $io;
        $this->attributeMediaGalleryEntryFactory = $attributeMediaGalleryEntryFactory;
        $this->imageContentFactory = $imageContentFactory;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->product=$product;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getRequiredFields() {
        return ['sku', 'image'];
    }

    /**
     * @param array $item
     */
    public function importSingle(array $item,$id) {
        if ($content = $this->getContentObject($item['image'])) {
            try {
                //$product = $this->productRepository->get($item['sku']);
                $product=$this->product->create()->load($id);
                $entries = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
                foreach ($entries as $entry) {
                    if (basename($entry->getFile()) === basename($content->getName())) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!isset($entry)) {
                    $entry = $this->attributeMediaGalleryEntryFactory->create();
                }
                $types= array('thumbnail', 'image', 'small_image','base_image');
                $entry->setContent($content);
                $entry->setMediaType('image');
                $entry->setTypes($types);
                $entry->setDisabled(false);
                $entries[] = $entry;
                $product->setMediaGalleryEntries($entries);
                $product->save();
                //$this->productRepository->save($product);
                return true;
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $ex) {
                $this->productImagelog($ex->getMessage());
                var_dump($ex->getMessage());exit;
                return false;
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException $ex) {
                $this->productImagelog($ex->getMessage());
                var_dump($ex->getMessage());exit;
                return false;
            }catch (\Exception $ex){
                $this->productImagelog($ex->getMessage());
                var_dump($ex->getMessage());exit;
                return false;
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * @param string $fileName
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Api\Data\ImageContentInterface|null
     */
    protected function getContentObject($image) {
        try{
            $srcPath = $image[0];
            $image_name = $image[1];
            if ($this->io->fileExists($srcPath)) {
                $content = $this->imageContentFactory->create();
                $content->setName(strtolower($image_name));
                $content->setBase64EncodedData(base64_encode(file_get_contents($srcPath)));
                $content->setType($this->mime->getMimeType($srcPath));
                return $content;
            }
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $ex) {
            $this->productImagelog($ex->getMessage());
            var_dump($ex->getMessage());exit;
            return false;
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException $ex) {
            $this->productImagelog($ex->getMessage());
            var_dump($ex->getMessage());exit;
            return false;
        }catch (\Exception $ex){
            $this->productImagelog($ex->getMessage());
            var_dump($ex->getMessage());exit;
            return false;
        }

        return null;
    }
    public function productImagelog($info) {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/product_image_sync.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info($info);
    }

}
```

Any suggestion how to resolve error

Comment: did u get any solution on this??

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the system tries to re-name an uploaded file without an extension; below is the function in Magento 2.3.6-p2 that avoids name conflicts:

```php
    /**
     * Get new file name if the same is already exists
     *
     * @param string $destinationFile
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getNewFileName($destinationFile)
    {
        $fileInfo = pathinfo($destinationFile);
        if (file_exists($destinationFile)) {
            $index = 1;
            $baseName = $fileInfo['filename'] . '.' . $fileInfo['extension'];
            while (file_exists($fileInfo['dirname'] . '/' . $baseName)) {
                $baseName = $fileInfo['filename'] . '_' . $index . '.' . $fileInfo['extension'];
                $index++;
            }
            $destFileName = $baseName;
        } else {
            return $fileInfo['basename'];
        }

        return $destFileName;
    }
```

This is the fixed function; I might create a PR for this, but at the moment, the best thing to do is just change `vendor/magento/framework/FileUploader.php` after every version upgrade, with the same sort of logic but not necessarily the same exact code:

```php
    /**
     * Get new file name if the same is already exists
     *
     * @param string $destinationFile
     * @return string
     */
    public static function getNewFileName($destinationFile)
    {
        $fileInfo = pathinfo($destinationFile);
        if (file_exists($destinationFile)) {
            $index = 1;
            $extension = isset($fileInfo['extension']) && array_key_exists('extension', $fileInfo) && trim($fileInfo['extension']) !== '' ? '.' . $fileInfo['extension'] : '';
            $baseName = $fileInfo['filename'] . $extension;
            while (file_exists($fileInfo['dirname'] . '/' . $baseName)) {
                $baseName = $fileInfo['filename'] . '_' . $index . $extension;
                $index++;
            }
            $destFileName = $baseName;
        } else {
            return $fileInfo['basename'];
        }

        return $destFileName;
    }
```

This checks for the existence of a file extension, and if no file extension exists, it just modifies the base filename.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when uploading a file with no extension in its name for second time.

`vendor/magento/framework/File/Uploader.php` file has a logic that appends a number to the filename when a file with the same name already exists. So, `picture.jpg` becomes `picture_1.jpg`. But when you upload a file named `picture` (with no extension), Magento also tries to construct a new filename with a number, but expects extension to be present too:

```php
$fileInfo = pathinfo($destinationFile);
$index = 1;
while ($fileExists($fileInfo['dirname'] . '/' . $fileInfo['basename'])) {
    $fileInfo['basename'] = $fileInfo['filename'] . '_' . $index++ . '.' . $fileInfo['extension'];
}
```

The error occurs, because there's no `extension` key in `$fileInfo` array.

Comment: Yes I am getting same error when adding the Vimeo URL.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you need to check if `$fileInfo['extension']` exists. In `vendor/magento/framework/File/Uploader.php`
If php is 7.4 version, then it would look like this(note new line 693):

[image]